# C# pass List<List<int>> to a Web Service

Tags: c#, list, web, service

The thread is exactly what I need,

I have this:

**WebService**:

```
....
List<List<Int64>> whau = new List<List<Int64>>();
....
[WebMethod]
static setList(List<List<Int64>> list_web)
{
    whau = list_web;
}
```

**C#**

```
public void func1 ()
{
    List<List<Int64>> list = new List<List<Int64>>();
    List<Int64> sublist = new List<Int64>();
    sublist.Add(1);
    sublist.Add(2);
    list.Add(sublist);

    service.setList(????);
}
```

But nothing works, I mean I've tried to send a `List` to the **WebService**, I used

```
sublist.ToArray()
```

and that works, but how to send the

```
List<List<>> var ?
```

Need really help !!

**Edit** :

I've already tried to do this :

```
service.setList(list);
```

and that works if the `WebMethod` is near the `func1()`, but of course the goal of **WebService** is not to be implemented in the same place that the Business Software...

Comment: `service.setList(list);` ??

Comment: service.setList(list); hmm?

Comment: Already tried it guys :) !

Comment: That s why I m just getting fool now... but if you have another way to send a T SQL table to a webservice... I take it :) !

Answer (score 0):

Change your `List<List<T>>` to `T[,]` and see if it works.

Your code will look like

```
....
Int64[,] whau = new Int64[X,Y]; // I don't know the size of this.
....
[WebMethod]
static setList(Int64[,] list_web)
{
    whau = list_web;
}

public void func1 ()
{
    Int64[,] list = Int64[1, 2];
    list[0, 1] = 1;
    list[0, 2] = 2;
    service.setList(list);
}
```

Remember that this is only an example. I don't know your actual code. This may cause compilation errors, but I think they will be easy to solve out.

Comment: ok I ll try it :) ! But what the code will be ? I don t know how to implement that ...

Comment: mhm...ok ! Let me try budy :D !

Comment: Finally, I try it but the send failed, so I tried another way to solve my problem... Thank you anyway !

Answer (score 0):

Ok budies,
so what I ve done is simple finally,
I just send a list to the webservice,
and the webservice recieve that list and insert it to another list, 
so is the WebService who creates the Nested List.

Thank you very much about your help you all !!

Regards !

FB